# Lot of objects in 3D games

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine

I have recently finished 3d model of lawn. I tried to run game with this 3d model but the fps result went so bad. The main problem is that there are a lot of grass an low fps. 
Pic is [here][1].

About month ago I played game with well known bald guy. There was incredible big corn field. 
Game screen: [Bald Guy Absolution][2]

It looks much better. There are much more object and it runs at twice as many fps.

I ask you why is that possible.
Unity developer can say that check "static" check box would resolve my problem. But it does not work.
I use

- low poly models
- low res texure ( transparent textures are as slow as normal diffuse).
- There is only one light.
- No fog.
- No LOD ( I don't think that this is the problem.)

Could you please tell me the reason why game that costs many milion dollars looks and works so much better and how I should change the setting to achieve that as well.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Um you don't have any images posted

Comment: this question is a better fit for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: I could not insert images. I have low reputation. Ever liks didn"t work. My screen - http://i.stack.imgur.com/o1081.jpg
Bald Guy Absolution is this http://guides.gamepressure.com/hitmanabsolution/gfx/word/363461062.jpg

Comment: Stats window says that you have 2847 draw calls. This is your main problem now.

Comment: See: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html
It means your scene essentially is sending an instruction to draw different objects 2847 times. The number doesn't reflect how many objects necessarily, since each object might require multiple draw calls based on lighting or shaders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a definitive answer, but some general info, and things to check.

Check the batching is actually working, there are many reasons why batching won't work - so always be attentive to the draw call count (click the stats button in the play window), if it doesn't change after turning static on, then it's not working. Check http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html for some reasons why that could be.

Are you drawing a single piece of grass at a time? Perhaps you need to have a clump of blades as a single object.

Are you using the grass on the built in landscaping? That could be relatively optimized compared to individually placing game objects.

You could change the model used based on the distance of the grass. One technique is to switch out the model (by fading) for textured quads when they are a certain distance away from the user to reduce poly count.

Always keep in mind these AAA games probably took more hours to develop, they will use a language with lower level access like C++ so they can squeeze out the performance for their particular use case, and dedicated shader programmers will get things looking great. Trying to program a AAA quality game on your own would require a massive amount of technical knowledge, time and dedication.